# FormControl returning empty value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am using a form

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" value={{userDetails.first_name}} formControlName = "firstName">
    <button type="submit" data-action="save" (click)="onSubmit(form.value)">
</form>
```

Here `userDetails.first_name` value is Tom. It is visible on UI inside text box ; but when I submit form `form.firstName` is giving me empty value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you should check `form.value.firstName` not `form.firstName`.

To have a better idea of how form is structured, do a `console.log(this.form)` on form submit.

Comment: I have done console.log ; still returning empty value

Comment: well, if `console.log(this.form)` returns an empty value probably there's something else wrong. Can you update your code with the component part too, not only the template?

Comment: Here is my **Form initialization** ``this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstname : new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required])) });``  & here is my **onSubmit method** ``onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);``

Answer (score 0):

Declare form group :

```
private userForm: FormGroup;
```

Initialize  user form like this:

```
  userForm = form.group({
          firstName:  [firstName, [Validators.required]]
        });
```

Declare your form  in HTML like this:

```
 <form class="example-form " [formGroup]="userForm"
                  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">
    <input type="text" value={{userDetails.firstName}} formControlName = 
      "firstName">
    <button type="submit" data-action="save"/>
 </form>
```

Make your onSubmit() method like this:

```
onSubmit({formValue, valid}: { formValue: UserDetails, valid: boolean }) {
    const firstName= value.firstName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    <button type="submit" data-action="save" (click)="onSubmit(form.value)">
</form>
```

**component**

you can set value like that

```
this.form.patchValue({firstName:this.userDetails.first_name});
```

make sure you create instance of form Group into component